# three images combinaison jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have 3 images and i want to switch between them !! each picture will take the place of the other !! there is a combinaiason but im stucked !! i don't know ifi'm doing the right way ! if there is is a simple way please tell it to m ill be gratefull !! thanx :)

Comment: What are you basically trying to do?

Comment: i have three images an image in the top with details and two other in the bottom !!when i click on one of the two images in the botton it take the place of the image in the top with details and the image with detail get the place of the picture in the bottom :) i hope you understand me

Answer (score 0):

This is just one of many ways to do this, but

**HTML**

```
    <div class="images">
        <div id="first-image">
            <img src="#1" />
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="#2" />
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="#3" />
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
        $(".images > div").click(function(){
            //check if the clicked div is first
            var check = $(this).parent().attr('id') == 'first-image';
            if(check); ///do nothing if it's the first image
            else {
                //get the content of the images to be switched
                var clickedContent = $(this).html();
                var firstImageContent = $('#first-image').html();

                //switch the contents of each
                $(this).html(firstImageContent);
                $('#first-image').html(clickedContent);
            }
        });
```

You identify where the first article is shown with an `id` and then just use it to reference the element while switching the content.

The demo can be seen with [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ePkAx/11/).

Answer (score 0):

hey i have created an jsfiddle example for you..

Code:-

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "img", function() {
        var htmlOfFirstDiv = $("#first").html();
        var currentDivHtml = $(this).closest("div").html();
        $("#first").html(currentDivHtml);
        $(this).closest("div").html(htmlOfFirstDiv)

    });

});
```

link:-
click here to see working example:-
http://jsfiddle.net/XUjAH/1091/

Comment: thank you guys i found the solution :) it was more easy that i thought :p